# How to check what action produced debug log?

Tags: debugging

Seeking for some insights on how to check which operation produced debug log?
Is there something within debug log that signifies what generated it?

Usually there's in 'Operation' column there's some sign on what action produced the log, but in this case it's showing 'N/A' in the 'Operation' column.

I need to regenerate the scenario to actually remove the exceptions found in the debug log.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5):

Each line in the debug log looks like this:

```
11:45:18.087 (87020000)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[13]|01p30000001i9gA|<init>()
```

Where the first value is a time stamp, the first value after the | is the type of module that was called (workflows, apex code, query, etc), the value inside the brackets (e.g. `[13]`) is the line of code that is at the current execution point, and `01p30000001i9gA` indicates the current class of execution (if any). From here, you will be able to isolate the exact line of code that was causing the failure. The error is usually self-evident once you have a specific line number; each line usually has only a few things that can be wrong with it (e.g. a null value, or a zero when it should be non-zero, etc).